# React 'useEffect' hook replaces how many lifecycle methods?

Tags: reactjs

How many lifecycle methods can be replaced by React `useEffect`?

I found an article on the `useEffect` hook that claims that it can replace only three, i.e. `componentDidMount`, `componentDidUpdate` and `componentWillUnmount`.

What about others?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope that's pretty much it, though it comes close to `componentWillUpdate` when you return a function and dont pass dependencies (it just doesn't run before the *first* render)

It's a really simple hook when you think about. The rules are pretty straightforward:

The function you pass to `useEffect`:

- runs after every render, unless you provide a dependency array.
- If you provide in a dependency array, it runs on first render, and then whenever the dependencies change.

The function your *return* from your `useEffect` function:

- Is run before each render (except the very first) unless you provide a dependency array.
- If you provide a dependency array, it is run before a render where the dependencies have changed, or the component unmounts.

It's probably best not to think about lifecycle events it replaces. Instead think about these 4 rules and how get them to run your functions when you want.

Answer (score 0):

That is actually all. useEffect() is called once component is mounted and than on every state update. If you want to use it as componentWillUnmout you have to return a cleanup function like so

```
useEffect(() => {
//something you want to do
return () => console.log('cleanup is running');
});
```